# multiple radial gradient with certain positions

Tags: html, css

Can someone show me how to do multiple radial gradients for chrome, IE and Mozilla. What I want is a radial gradient on the righthand side starting from 200px and the another gradient starting from 50% and then a gradient at the bottom in the centre. I have had no luck in creating this could someone show me please how to do this in one div that's 100% height. I also want these gradients only showing half the circle coming out from the edges. Your help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

So:

- One gradient that occupies the full width
- One gradient that is offset by 200px from the right
- One gradient that is half the height of the page, covering the bottom half
- All three gradients must be compatible with all browsers

Correct? That would look something like this:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

#grad_full_width {
  height: 150px;
  width: 100vw;
  background: -webkit-radial-gradient(red, green, blue);
  /* Safari 5.1 to 6.0 */
  background: -o-radial-gradient(red, green, blue);
  /* For Opera 11.6 to 12.0 */
  background: -moz-radial-gradient(red, green, blue);
  /* For Firefox 3.6 to 15 */
  background: radial-gradient(red, green, blue);
  /* Standard syntax (must be last) */
}

#grad_offset_right {
  position: absolute;
  right: 200px;
  top: 0;
  height: 150px;
  width: 100vw;
  background: -webkit-radial-gradient(green, blue, yellow);
  /* Safari 5.1 to 6.0 */
  background: -o-radial-gradient(green, blue, yellow);
  /* For Opera 11.6 to 12.0 */
  background: -moz-radial-gradient(green, blue, yellow);
  /* For Firefox 3.6 to 15 */
  background: radial-gradient(green, blue, yellow);
  /* Standard syntax (must be last) */
}

#grad_bottom {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  height: 50vh; /* 50% of the height */
  width: 100vw;
  background: -webkit-radial-gradient(green, blue, yellow);
  /* Safari 5.1 to 6.0 */
  background: -o-radial-gradient(green, blue, yellow);
  /* For Opera 11.6 to 12.0 */
  background: -moz-radial-gradient(green, blue, yellow);
  /* For Firefox 3.6 to 15 */
  background: radial-gradient(green, blue, yellow);
  /* Standard syntax (must be last) */
}
```

```html
<div id="grad_full_width"></div>
<div id="grad_offset_right"></div>
<div id="grad_bottom"></div>
```

You can achieve **half** circles by simply offsetting them so that their center is the edge of the page.

Hope this helps! :)